# Updating entities in Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I have a few entities, who's positions are being set using a CallbackProperty function.

```
cesium.renderPolygon = function(mapContext, polygon, existingEntity) {
            var p;
            if (existingEntity) {
                p = existingEntity;
            } else {
                var polOpts = getStyleOptions(polygon.style);
                // function for getting location
                polygon.getHierarachy = new Cesium.CallbackProperty(function(time, result) {
                    var hierarchy = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < polygon.coordinates.length; i++) {
                        var coordinate = polygon.coordinates[i];
                        hierarchy.push(Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(coordinate.longitude, coordinate.latitude, coordinate.altitude));
                    }
                    return hierarchy;
                }, false);

                polOpts.hierarchy = polygon.getHierarachy;

                p = mapContext.entities.add({
                    name: polygon.name,
                    polygon: polOpts
                });
            }
            return p;
        };
```

If I add a single entity, it seems to work great. As I add more there is a delay (1-3 seconds) and then all entities do not update nicely. It looks really bad.

Is there a way to limit the number of times this updates the entities. I have been reading the Cesium documentation, but cannot find anything on this.

Or is there a better way to dynamically and consistently update entities?

Comment: You didn't supply enough information and code to indicate what the problem could be.  Is your CallbackProperty implementation really that simple?  Where do longitude/latitude/altitude come from and how are they updated?  What kind of visualization are you doing (billboard/model/etc..)?  What does your update look look like?  You should be passing result as the 4th parameter to fromDegrees, but that's probably not the main problem (though will definitely affect performance).

Comment: I have added a more complete code sample. What is the '4th parameter to fromDegrees' referring to?

Comment: https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Cartesian3.html - 4th parameter is ellipsoid on which the position lies (Ellipsoid.fromCartesian3 Ellipsoid.WGS84 or Ellipsoid.UNIT_SPHERE)

Answer (score 1):

The Cesium guide claims that the Entity API is able to provide flexible, high-performance visualization while exposing a consistent, easy to learn, and easy to use interface.
I have the experience to tell you that updating from outside of cesium works faster. You can also utilize the EntitiCollection (https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/EntityCollection.html?classFilter=EntityCol) to getByID, suspendEvents and removeEvents to orchestrate cesium to update only when you are ready.
We were able to update 1000 entities every 200ms that way without hurting performance at all. We figured out that if you want better results (like 10k entities every 200ms) you will need to implement your own shader.

Comment: Thanks for the response, scaling is the problem for sure. I have about 15k entities all being updated at various rates. I have neglected this post a bit, but looking into taking control of the events seems like a good idea. What are you referring to with "Shader"?

Comment: Implementing your own shader means implementing your own vertex shader (and logic) on top of webGl, and connect it to cesium display. See discussion here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/NyQ-woOhWtU

Comment: Could you elaborate some on what you mean by updating outside of Cesium? I too have 300,000+ entities that are constantly moving and the frame rate slows to nothing. Do you mean "shut-off" events that impact entities and emit them yourself only when needed?